# Django REST framework - nested query JSON

Tags: json, django-rest-framework

In django REST framework on API recieved JSON:

```
{
    "field1": "value1",
    "field2": 975.0,
    "superField": [
        {
            "sField1": 123.0,
            "sField2": "s_value1",
            "megaField": {
                "mFieldID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                "mField_name": "MegaName1"
            }
        },
        {
            "sField1": 456.0,
            "sField2": "s_value2",
            "megaField": {
                "mFieldID": "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111",
                "mField_name": "MegaName2"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

file models.py:

```
class Table0(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    field2 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    k_tableS = models.ManyToManyField('TableM', through='TableS')


class TableS(models.Model):
    s_field1 = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    s_field2 = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    k_megafield = models.ForeignKey('TableM', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='TableM')
    k_table0 = models.ForeignKey('Table0', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Table0')


class TableM(models.Model):
    m_fieldID = models.UUIDField()
    m_field_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

file serializers.py:

```
class TableSSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = TableS
        fields = '__all__'


class TableMSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = TableM
        fields = '__all__'


class Table0Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    supefield = TableSSerializer()
    megafield = TableMSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Table0
        fields = '__all__'
```

file urls.py:

```
my_rout = routers.DefaultRouter()
my_rout.register(r'super', Table0ViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/v1/', include(my_rout.urls))
]
```

file views.py:

```
class Table0ViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Table0.objects.all()
    serializer_class = Table0Serializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        breakpoint()
        supefields_data = request.data.pop('supefield')

        serializer = Table0Serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        table0 = serializer.save()

        for s_data in supefields_data:
            megafield_data = s_data.pop('megafield')
            megafield_serializer = TableMSerializer(data=megafield_data)
            megafield_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            megafield = megafield_serializer.save()
            s_data['k_megafield'] = megafield.id
            s_d_serializer = TableSSerializer(data=s_data)
            s_d_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            supefield = s_d_serializer.save()

        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

Here **.create** doesn't work because I'm trying to write data to **Table0** before how to write related data in **TableM** and **TableS**. So I'm thinking, how right? I don't understand how to correctly write data to the database... How to change models.py, serializers.py and views.py for API to work correctly